# colab face mask implementation?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, opencv

I was trying to implement face mask detecting system from this [**blog**](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/04/covid-19-face-mask-detector-with-opencv-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/). I got an error in the `detect_mask_image.py` file:

```
File "/content/drive/My Drive/mask/face-mask-detector/detect_mask_image.py", line 32, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "face_detector/deploy.prototxt" in function 'ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```

Why this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Colab to detect a live video from your webcam then you have to make some changes to allow WEB APIs to access the local hardware such as the webcam.

Here is a [link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi) to help.